# replace special characters by its phoenetic similar character (in php - utf8)

Tags: php, replace, special-characters, transliteration

you know that there are many characters like è or é. There are many more, like ö,ä,ì,á,ù,...

i want to replace those characters with its "phoenetic partner"-character, but i don't want to do it for each single character like

```
str_replace(array("á", "à", "é", "è", ...), array("a", "a", "e", "e", ...), &$input);
```

is there any common way to do something like:

```
str_replace_phoenetical(&$input)
```

- has anybody still wirtten a script
  which covers all cases?
- is there a    way to automaticly
  detect those    characters and just
  remove the ` or    '?

thanks so far

**UPDATE:**

does anyone reccomands [this one (found on php.net)](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php#96586)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can transliterate them with [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

```
$str = 'áàéè';

$transliterated = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);

var_dump($transliterated); // string(4) "aaee"
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/r8GAX).

Comment: my target representation is utf-8 as well as the source ... what can I do? shell I put it into ascii and then back to utf8?

Comment: @helle The characters should work fine as ASCII transliterated because the first 255 ASCII characters map to their UTF-8 equivalents I believe.

Comment: @helle: All ASCII *is* UTF-8.

Comment: @alex: ASCII only goes up to 127 (plus 0).

Comment: @helle Is your page you are viewing sending `Content-Type: UTF-8` ? The CodePad example works fine :)

Comment: `mb_detect_encoding($myinput)` says UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

[unidecode](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-unidecode)

Comment: do I have to add all those files to my project only to get an e from an è? or is there an easier way?

Comment: To be fair, unidecode covers a *lot* more than just accented roman characters.